# how to use libtbb.so in mkl with tensorflow

Tags: c++, tensorflow, tbb, intel-mkl

I compile tensorflow with --config=mkl, And I want to use tbb in mkl, but is's only use libiomp5.so,how to use libtbb.so

```
ldd tensorflow/bazel-tensorflow/external/mkl/lib/libmklml_intel.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffefb88d000)
        libiomp5.so => not found
        libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ff1c0fe5000)
        libm.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007ff1c0ce3000)
        libc.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff1c0922000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff1ca13a000)
```